# Subsonic/Linq Not a sequence error what does it mean

Tags: linq, subsonic

Hi I am getting this error. 
The expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String]' is not a sequence.

this is my code

```
_session.All<Sentence>()
        .Select(T => new { Sentence = T, Descriptions = T.Sentence.Split(' ') })
        .Where(S => S.Descriptions .Intersect(words).Any())
        .Select(R => R.Sentence)
        .Distinct();
```

`words` is a list of string.

what does not a sequence mean and how do i fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Okay, now that the question's been corrected...

I *suspect* this is a Subsonic restriction. You might try this instead:

```
.Where(S => S.Descriptions.Any(x => words.Contains(x)))
```

Comment: Hi sorry it was a typing mistake. I have it as .Where(S => S.Descriptions.Intersect(words).Any()) in my code but it seems I posted the wrong code.

Comment: @user351709: If you remove the `Where` line, does it work (except it obviously gives you too many results)? My guess is that this is just a subsonic restriction...